# Valid global .gitignore steps won't take effect on Mac OS

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to set-up global gitignore file on Mac OS but for some reason it doesn't take effect. When I repeat same steps on Linux OS then all go fine. Steps below what I do. Could anyone point out what I'm missing please?

Note: I committed .idea files before so would this be related to it? Just in case I tried adding `.idea` and `.idea/*` as well.

**STEPS**

```
MacBook-Pro:~ bc$ echo $HOME
/Users/bc
MacBook-Pro:~ bc$ git config --get core.excludesfile
/Users/bc/.gitignore_global
MacBook-Pro:~ bc$ cat .gitignore_global
*~
.DS_Store
.idea/
MacBook-Pro:~ bc$ git config --global core.excludesfile /Users/bc/.gitignore_global
```

**PROJECT**

```
MacBook-Pro:Project bc$ git branch
* develop
  master
MacBook-Pro:Project bc$ git status
On branch develop
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .idea/workspace.xml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git’s ignores (be they local or global) only pertain to files that have not been added to the index. Once a file is part of the repository, git will continue tracking changes to it, no matter the current ignore list. You need to remove the file from the index using

```
git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml
```

Alternatively, you can tell git to keep tracking the file but ignore local changes using

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged .idea/workspace.xml
```

Comment: I thought so! Nice one. I've just run `rm -r .git`, `git init` and `git status`. Problem solved. Thank you.